# How to derive $\frac{d}{dn}n! = \Gamma(1 + n)\psi^{(0)}(n+ 1)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, factorial, gamma-function

How can you derive $\frac{d}{dn}n! = \Gamma(1 + n)\psi^{(0)}(n + 1)$? I have tried checking Wolfram Alpha for a step-by-step solution, but none is given. Moreover, of what is the second function, $\psi^{(0)}$, representative?

Comment: The second function is often defined as $\phi^{(n)} (x)=\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}\ln \Gamma (x)$. The identity then follows from the chain rule.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dn}n!$ does not make sense, $n!$ is not continuous like $\Gamma(x)$

Comment: I'm only re-iterating what I saw on Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score -2):

$\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$

$\Gamma(n+1)=n!$

${d\over{dn}}n!={d\over{dn}}\Gamma(n+1)$

now just look arround you for the derivative of the gamma function